# How can I extend my hard disk partition in Linux?

Tags: partitioning

I have a 10GB partition which I want to extend to 20GB.

I have free space on my hard disk. What should I do to extend the partition?

Comment: Sorry, this was not meant to be converted to community wiki.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try downloading, burning and booting with a Linux live CD, Ubuntu for example, and using gparted to resize your partitions.

Comment: can you tel me the statement which i need to give to extend the parition 10 to 20gb

Comment: gparted is a graphical application, you can drag and drop to the size that you want and click the Apply Changes button.

Answer (score 0):

You could try downloading, burning and booting with a Linux live CD, Ubuntu for example, and using gparted to resize your partitions.